# Assigning classes in Java

Tags: java

I have

```
  SomeClass sc1 = new SomeClass();
  SomeClass sc2 = sc1;
```

Will sc2 change due to sc1(when sc1 is changed) ?
If not, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes any changes to `sc1` will be reflected in `sc2` as both of the point to the same object.

So to say if this is the structure of `SomeClass`

```
public SomeClass {
  String name;
  //getter setter
}
```

if you do this

```
SomeClass sc1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass sc2 = sc1;

sc1.setName("Hello");

System.out.println(sc2.getName()); // this will print hello since both sc1 and sc2 are pointing to the same object.
```

But if you do this:

```
sc1.setName("Hello");
sc1 = null;
System.out.println(sc2.getName()); // this will print hello since only sc1 is null not sc2.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes of couse, because they both refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Its like - giving sc1 an additional name sc2.

Answer (score 0):

`sc2` and `sc1` are separate variables that both contain *references* to the same object (this is an important distinction!). Any change to the object's state will be equally visible through both references. So

```
sc2.setField("hi!");
sc1.getField(); // returns "hi!"
```

However, changes to the references themselves have no effect on the other:

```
sc2 = null;
sc1.getField(); // still returns "hi!", no exception
```